# How to completely export XML Sitemap configuration settings?

Tags: 8, xml-sitemap

I have the XML Sitemap installed on a few sites, but due to SEO concerns, I am now tasked to enable the module on all sites that we support. I have an update hook ready, but I'm running into an issue importing the configurations.

When I export the xmlsitemap.settings.yml file, I just get  the following:

```
minimum_lifetime: 0
xsl: 1
prefetch_aliases: 1
chunk_size: auto
batch_limit: 100
path: xmlsitemap
frontpage_priority: !!float 1
frontpage_changefreq: 86400
lastmod_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i\Z'
gz: false
clean_url: 0
disable_cron_regeneration: false
i18n_selection_mode: simple
```

I have rules setup for Media and Content, but as you can see it only picks up Frontpage. The goal is to make all these settings true for all the sites I handle.

I'd appreciate any help. thanks!

Comment: Might be worth looking into https://www.drupal.org/project/features to see if it can do what you need

Comment: Looks like there's an answer on the module issues queue. https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap/issues/3116026